# Modal dialog- the modal is shown and closed immediately

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a modal window with a submit button.
When the user clicks on the button there is an ajax call:

```
  $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "${createLink(controller:'userInvitation', action:'ajaxUpdate')}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#invitationForm").serialize(),
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
//                        $('#invitationForm')[0].reset();
                        $('.request-invitation-modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#thank-you-modal').modal('show');
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //alert('error:' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
    }
```

For some reason the modal window with the thank-you-modal is shown for less than a second and closed.

I use bootstrap 3.3.4

http://jsfiddle.net/sarit8/5qzuyx12 is without the css.... I did it only for the html and js so ignore the result which displayed.

Comment: Can you show HTML. Create fiddle if possible

Comment: Without seeing the html, I would guess that your '#thank-you-modal' has a class of 'request-invitation-modal', so it is being closed by the 'hide' method.

Comment: @Sam Tyson-it hasn't

Comment: @saritrotshild in your HTML, I see `data-target=".thank-you-modal"` - that should be `#thank-you-modal`.

Comment: The problem was in the button type. It shouldn't be submit